# Python multiprocessing pool performance difference on two different machines

Tags: python, intel, python-multiprocessing

So I have deployed the same code on two different machines in the same python virtual env, the OS/kernel are exactly the same, and hard drive model is the same. The only major difference between the two machines is the CPUs. Machine 1 has 2x Xeon E5-2690 (16 cores @ 2.90 ghz) and machine 2 has 1x Xeon W3690 (6 cores at 3.47 ghz).

Now when I run a version of the code which does not use the multiprocessing Pool, machine 1 will run faster. However when using multiprocessing Pool, machine 2 will run significantly faster (greater than 6x). In fact machine 1 will not run that much quicker than the single threaded version, no matter how many threads I create.

The process in question just reads HDF5 files and performs some basic mathematical operations on the data.

It was suggested to me to run strace -c, my results show that a bit more time is spent on futex on machine 1. However since I only ran it once, there's no real statistical certainty there.

I'm pretty sure the issue is related to the overhead created by multiprocessing, however that's quite a large differential. I also find it difficult to believe that .57 ghz would cause that large of a discrepancy too. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

So here's a test I ran without having to deal with IO:

Machine 1:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import multiprocessing

In [3]: def gen_rand(x):
        return np.random.random(x)
   ...: 

In [4]: pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)

In [5]: proc_arg = 100*[100000]

In [6]: %timeit -n30 pool.map(gen_rand, proc_arg)
30 loops, best of 3: 254 ms per loop
```

Machine 2:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import multiprocessing

In [3]: def gen_rand(x):
        return np.random.random(x)
   ...: 

In [4]: pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)

In [5]: proc_arg = 100*[100000]

In [6]: %timeit -n30 pool.map(gen_rand, proc_arg)
30 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop
```

Comment: How many processes are you launching on each machine? Have you measured disk usage while processing? Maybe more concurrent I/O is leading to worse performance? What OS are you running on?

Comment: Also, on the machine that has 2 CPUs, have you tried to pin your processes only to the cores of one of the physical CPUs?

Comment: So the base comparison is 6 processes on each machine, but I also ran with 12 processes on the machine 1 simply to check if performance would increase by much (the answer turned out to be no). RHEL Server 6.5. Is there a good way to measure disk usage? I'm just using sar and appears like iowait is higher on machine 2.

Comment: There's no difference if I taskset the process

Comment: besides iowait, you can measure throughput with `iotop`. How is CPU usage when you run the processes? I don't think multiprocessing would have much overhead, unless your task is small or you communicate or synchronize a lot

Comment: So I can't use iotop or iowait since I don't have root privileges to install them. However, I'm not entirely convinced that it's completely an IO problem, I just updated the original post with some tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61667/discussion-between-goncalopp-and-ast4).